# Infinite sequence of bases for a topological space

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Give an example of a topological space $X$ and an infinite sequence of bases, $\mathcal{B}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{B}_2, \ldots$ such that
> $$
> \mathcal{B}_1 \not \supset \mathcal{B}_2 \not \supset \mathcal{B}_3 \not \supset \ldots
> $$
> all generating the same topology $\mathcal{T}$.

The setup of the problem is a bit confusing, because though I'm choosing a sequence and the order matters, it seems that I can have, for example,  $\mathcal{B}_1 \supset \mathcal{B}_3$ and this restriction only applies to consecutive elements. I'm trying to understand exactly why that is significant, because it isn't that the sequence is anti-nested in the sense that $\mathcal{B}_i \subset \mathcal{B}_{i+1}$ for every $i$.

The most natural topological space to me seems to be $X = \mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology. The most natural basis is the set of all open intervals. I'm wondering if I can just "enlarge the intervals" and generate another countable basis that doesn't include all open such open intervals. For example, if I have $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$, I can take their union and include $b$. This isn't rigorous at this point, though.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a typo and that the condition should be $\cal B_1 \supsetneq \cal B_2 \supsetneq \cal B_3 \supsetneq \dotsm$?

Comment: The meaning is clear when you have a string of subsets or supersets, because $\subset$ and $\supset$ are both transitive relations. But $\not\subset$ and $\not\supset$ are not transitive relations. So $A\not\supset B \not\supset C$ is unclear. Certainly the two immediate relations are understood, but do you mean for there to be any implication about $A$ and $C$? Because of the non-transitivity, the statement does not imply any relationship between them. But if so, why string them together like this, as is usually used to imply some relationship?